Unable to install modules in python 3.12.6 through command prompt
I have installed Python 3.12.6 with idle Python, Python, Python module docs.
All 64bit versions are in version 3.12 respectively but I can not seem to install modules.
I did this in the command prompt:
C:\Users\my user name>pip3 -v
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\my user name>pip3 install numpy
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

and that happened I tried typing the same stuff in Python and used pip as well and it did not work.

Try and use pip instead of pip3.

Can you run python and python3?

In a case like that, python -m pip install numpy is recommended.

The usual command is pip, not pip3.  Why are you using pip3?

It is better firstly to create a virtual environment with terminal:
    python -m venv venv

or
    py -m venv venv

After intall libraries:
    pip instal numpy pandas # You can list several


If "pip" doesn't work before creating a virtual environment. it's not going to work after.
